# Flutter - Save file visible to the user

Tags: file, pdf, flutter, storage, store

In a Flutter project I create a pdf document. I can save the document in the path of the app.
But the user has no access to it. Alternatively, how can I save the file to another folder where the user sees it?

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
  Future<void> savePdfDocument() async {
    final PdfCreater generatedPdf = PdfCreater(document);
    final List<int> generatedPdfDocument = generatedPdf.buildPdf();

    final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    final String path = '$dir/example.pdf';
    final File file = File(path);
    file.writeAsBytesSync(generatedPdfDocument);
  }
```

Comment: Since you're saving file in Documents directory, user can see it, he may need to go to `android/data/data/your_package_name/` folder, if you want to save the file in root directory, you can simply change the path, but make sure you have access to storage permission in Android.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad That aint true, the path from `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` isnt accessible to the user. The name can be misleading, its not the documents folder that you see in your phone's File menu

Comment: @West Yes, I knew the `document` folder ins't the one which is at the root of your SD card directory. I thought it's the `android/data/package/files` one but turned out it's `data/data/package/app_flutter/` which indeed ins't accessible to the user.

Answer (score 12):

Use [downloads_path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider), on android it will save the file on Downloads.

for IOS, you need to use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory`from path_provider and add permissions on `info.plist` to make the folder visible to the user:

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: 8 Jan 2021: This plugin has lots of inconsistencies and should no longer be used. Feel free to fork and tweak it.

Comment: If you can't view your files with path_provider in the files app on iOS, this permission will allow you to view them.

Answer (score 2):

This works like a charm

```
String documentsPath = '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/';
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  documentsPath = path.path;
}
```

Also don't forgot to add this to pubspec
path_provider: 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Also, be sure to test on a physical device, iOS emulator won't work.