# How do I ensure that downloaded images and videos stored in my android devices external storage directory can be accessed from the android gallery?

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am in the process of creating a flutter app and I am trying to download images and videos from the internet that can be accessed and displayed in the androids gallery app, I have managed to create a directory with the following path "storage/emulated/0/myDir" and download the images and videos successfully into that folder but I am unable to access them in the devices gallery app.

Does any know of what is needed to be done in order for this to happen.

I'd prefer a method where I am not using the ImageGallerySaver Plugin or GallerySaverPlugin, as they don't allow me to create my own storage path.

Comment: You should let the media store scanner scan every downloaded file. Or reboot your device.

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59629863/11708327

Comment: Hello, I have another query for you @blackapps, I have fixed my issue and I am now seeing the images I download from the internet in my devices gallery, however I find that whenever I upload an image to a cloud storage that was taken from my device's camera then download it again onto my device the timestamp given to the image downloaded, in the gallery app, is the same time stamp as the original photo graph that was taken. Is there a way around this or is this just something android devices do?

Comment: An Android device does nothing. Only apps do things. Which app did you use?

Comment: The gallery app is recording the same timestamp as the original photo graph before it is uploaded to a cloud storage and after it has been downloaded into a separate directory so I have two of the same photos in the gallery app with the same timestamps despite them having different time stamps in the androids internal directory.